# Extending ComboBox ItemsSource Collection in LostFocus Event of the ComboBox

Tags: data-binding, wpf-controls

I am using a ComboBox in an WPF application. The ComboBox displays items from the ItemsSource which is a ObservableCollection of Type SourceItem. The ComboBox has IsEditable enabled, so the user may enter new values.
When the user enters a new value the new value will be added to the ItemsSource Collection which is populating the list part of the combobox.

Below you find the ListBox which carries a data binding on a CollectionView to fill a ListBox:

```
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewAktion}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            x:Name="listBox" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="362" Margin="100,46,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" MinWidth="200"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SourceName}" MinWidth="200"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tBlock" 
                                   Text="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, ElementName=cbMain}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                   Width="119"/>
                        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="tBlock1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=cbMain}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                   Margin="0" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                   Width="119"/>-->
                        <ComboBox
                          x:Name="cbMain"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemSourceCollection, ElementName=listBox}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"
                          SelectedValuePath="ItemName"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SourceName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox}"
                          IsEditable="True" LostFocus="cbMain_LostFocus" PreviewKeyDown="cbMain_PreviewKeyDown"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

For testing purpose, I used a fixed value "Walter". When I enter "Walter" into the ComboBox of one item of the covering ListBox, it works as expected. "Walter" is added to the ItemsSource and "Walter" set in the item in the CollectionView correctly.

```
       private void cbMain_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (sender is not ComboBox)
                return;

            String sNewValue= "Walter";
            String sDesperateTry = "";
         //  sDesperateTry = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
         //  sNewValue = sDesperateTry;

            bool bMakeNew = _vm.ItemSourceCollection.Any(obj => obj.ItemName == sNewValue );

            if (!bMakeNew)
            {
                SourceItem newItem = new SourceItem();
                newItem.Id = 5;
                newItem.ItemName = sNewValue;
                
                _vm.ItemSourceCollection.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
```

As soon as I try to get the value from the sender parameter of the event handler, which I considered only a formal step, by removing the comment signs:

```
   sDesperateTry = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
   sNewValue = sDesperateTry;
```

the sNewValue will not be used in the CollectionView and Databinding is not working directly. The new item is added to the ItemsSource and has to be selected manually to get the databinding working.

It doesn't matter if I use the value or not, as soon as I read the Text property the data binding isn't working as before.